# XP_CMDSHELL returns "The syntax of this command is:"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to make another drive available through SQL.

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use G: \\IMAFS01\Finance'
```

works fine but

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'net use J: \\IMA-SQL01\Microsoft SQL Server 2016 /user:[XXX\xxx] /persistent:yes'
```

returns the message below.  There is no password and I have full control of the folder.

This is what the output says:

```
The syntax of this command is:
NULL
NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]
NULL
NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME
NULL
NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: You have spaces in the folder name. Enclose the entire path in double quotes and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.

Comment: Here is the code that worked:        exec xp_cmdshell 'net use J: "\\IMA-SQL01\Microsoft SQL Server 2016" /user:XXX\xxx <Password> /persistent:yes'